# comparing dates and event occurrence dilemma

Tags: t-sql

I have a table as follows:

```
PatientID  DiseaseCode  DiseaseDate
1          xhd8         23-5-2006
1          nxhd         07-9-2013
2          kdeh         15-3-1998
```

where:

- xhd8 = diabetes
- nxhd = diabetes has resolved(cured)
- kdeh = heart disease

How can I write a single query, to tell me if this patient(#1) still actively diagnosed as diabetic, the logic should be like this:
does patient have xhd8? if yes-> does he have nxhd(cured)?-> was it cured ***after*** he was diagnosed? if yes->don't show me the patient, if he doesn't have resolved code or it was recorded as resolved before the diagnosis then show me the patient.

in the above example, the patient diabetes has resolved(cured) after diagnosis, so it wouldn't return anything. however in the example below, I would expect the patient record to be returned:

```
PatientID  DiseaseCode  DiseaseDate
1          xhd8         23-8-2014
1          nxhd         09-3-1996
2          kdeh         15-3-1998
```

unfortunately changing the db schema is beyond my permission.

any ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Show us your attempt that did not give you the expected output.

Comment: I don't understand where you expected dates are coming from, and also that is not the expected output I would imagine by reading the text in your question.

Comment: I don't really know where to start, any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` should do the trick. Note my examples and comments.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (PatientID  int, DiseaseCode  varchar(10), DiseaseDate date);
INSERT @table VALUES
(1,'xhd8','20060523'),
(1,'nxhd','20130907'),
(2,'kdeh','19980315');

-- Should return nothing
SELECT *
FROM @table t
WHERE t.DiseaseCode = 'xhd8'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM @table t2
  WHERE t.PatientID = t2.PatientID
  AND t2.DiseaseCode = 'nxhd'
  AND t2.DiseaseDate > t.DiseaseDate
);

DELETE FROM @table;

INSERT @table VALUES
(1,'xhd8','20140823'),
(1,'nxhd','19960309'),
(2,'kdeh','19980315');

-- should return employee ID=1 with diseaseCode = 'xhd8'
SELECT *
FROM @table t
WHERE t.DiseaseCode = 'xhd8'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM @table t2
  WHERE t.PatientID = t2.PatientID
  AND t2.DiseaseCode = 'nxhd'
  AND t2.DiseaseDate > t.DiseaseDate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you might try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(PatientID  INT,DiseaseCode VARCHAR(10),  DiseaseDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'xhd8','23-5-2006')
,(1,'nxhd','07-9-2013')
,(2,'kdeh','15-3-1998');

SELECT MostCurrenntDiabetes.*
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES t.*
    FROM @tbl t
    WHERE t.DiseaseCode IN('xhd8','nxhd')
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.PatientID ORDER BY t.DiseaseDate DESC)
) AS MostCurrenntDiabetes
--WHERE MostCurrenntDiabetes.DiseaseCode='xhd8';
```

Using `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` together with a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` will return **all rows with a `1` as sort-rank**. This means, that you get the last (youngest) row for each patient.

The `WHERE` in the inner `SELECT` will reduce the rows to patients with any diabetes related diseasecode (any other will not show up at the end.

The final `WHERE` will return just these patients, where the *youngest* code is *xhd8*. I commented this, to avoid an empty set.

Might be you need something else...